# How do I run Autocad 13 (not 2013, but #13) on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-xp

Do I try to get Ubuntu to run it or is there a compatible CAD program for Ubuntu that sees Autocad files? When I try to install, it is asking for a 32bit system. I last had it running in XP

Comment: Autocad does not have a Linux version as far as I know but for as an alternative, there is always [3DS DraftSight](http://askubuntu.com/a/48703/449) which is monetarily free.

Comment: At the risk of going off topic- try AutoCADws for google chrome. I've used it only a couple times, but did it's job.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a vm (let's say windows 7) in virtualbox and install autocad in it. You just need a somewhat powerful machine