# Is it possible to install AutoCad or an alternative on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, software-recommendation, cad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What good CAD programs are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26954/what-good-cad-programs-are-available)

My relative wants to install Ubuntu for his office purposes. He would definitely use AutoCad (as well as other tools).

Would AutoCAD work in Ubuntu? Or are there any alternatives?

Comment: AutoCAD is Windows only, and won't work in Ubuntu.

Comment: Please ask about the "other tools" in separate questions (and specify what these "other tools" are).

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/26954/what-good-cad-programs-are-available

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are numerous options, choose the one that you like best.

1. [PyCAD](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/pythoncad/)
2. [Medusa](http://www.cad-schroer.com/):

   - Download the free software for personal use.
   - Download: `medusa4_v4_0_0_linux_personal.sh`
   - After downloading the above file, it needs to be marked as executable, so it can be run. To do this, run: `chmod +x <filename.sh>` in a terminal
   - It needs to be executed as root, so use sudo: `sudo ./filename.sh`
   - Installation & More information: [Here](http://worldcadaccess.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/installing-medusa4-on-linux.html)
3. [Draftsight](http://www.3ds.com/products/draftsight/free-cad-software/) - may be unstable under Linux but is written for it. YMMV.
4. Librecad

   - Its already in Ubuntu Repositories.
   - You can get it by running: `sudo apt-get install librecad`
   - More Information: [Librecad](http://librecad.org/cms/home/installation/linux.html)
5. [Bricscad](https://www.bricsys.com/en_INTL/bricscad/#) is a very stable paid application that is a very close Autocad clone.  It is not free however my experience is that it is stable and edits 99% of Autocad functions.

Comment: Draftsight is very close to Autodesk Autocad, I have a very good impression on it