# Application to draw electrical instalations

Tags: software-recommendation, cad

Are there any good Linux applications for drawing electro fittings? I haven't been able to find any...Usually these fittings are drawn in the Autocad software.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these options.

[LibreCAD](http://librecad.org/cms/home.html) is a free Open Source CAD application for Windows, Apple and Linux.

[DraftSight](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight/) is the only native software running on Ubuntu compatible with DWG files - it's 2D only (can view 3D files but not create them), sort of an equivalent to AutoCAD LT.

**If you want to spend money then**

[Bricscad](http://www.bricsys.com/en_INTL/bricscad/) is a lot more powerful, has ACIS modeling just like AutoCAD (Pro version) and its Platinum version has even parametric modeling.

Comment: didnt get you? did you meant commenting on question

Comment: ok will do that

Comment: did it http://askubuntu.com/a/365529/190009